# How to set a button component's transition option to "none" via C# in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I need to setup my button components in Unity to look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F5UKO.png) via C# (i.e. with "Transition" and "Navigation" set to "None").

For the Navigation, it was a little unintuitive but I eventually found that this worked:

```
Navigation customNav = new Navigation();
customNav.mode = Navigation.Mode.None;
myButton.navigation = customNav;
```

But I can't for the life of me find a equivalent for "Transition". If it's in the documentation, it must be buried under a heading I can't find. Does anyone have any idea how it can be done?

Comment: Can you provide the unity version you are using plz?

Comment: LTS Release 2019.4

Comment: why do I always get a -1 on Unity questions....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the transition value by assigning a `Selectable.Transition` type enum value to the `.transition` property.

## Example

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class TestScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private Button target = null;

    private void Start()
    {
        target.transition = Selectable.Transition.None;
    }
}
```

## Reference

https://docs.unity3d.com/2017.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.Selectable-transition.html